# Character Encoding downloading text from a web page

Tags: android, html, character-encoding, inputstreamreader

I am trying to get some text from an HTML page, I can download correctly but the accents in spanish (á, é, í, ó, ú) and probably other special caracters ( ü ) are being showed like a square with a ? mark inside.

Once the InputStreamReader I use calls the read function, the text already appears like this, however the HTML page and the database that stores the content are fine.

Is there anyway to specify to the InputStreamReader what character encoding it should be expecting? I am using utf8_general_ci originally in the database, and then showing it into a php page that obtains the text.

Thanks.

```
private String DownloadText (String URL)
{
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
    InputStream in = null;
    try
    {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return "";
    }

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
    int charRead;
    String str = "";
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    try
    {
        charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer);
        str = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
        inputBuffer = null;
        in.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        return "";
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this header

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

and after you connect to your DB like this

```
// Connect to server and select database.
$login = mysql_connect("www.yoursite.com","username","password") 
or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("yourDatabase", $login);
```

add those two lines

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Comment: Amazing. I was doing all my changes on the Android app and it only required to change how the information was being retrieved in the php page. 
Thank you very much, great help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), BUFFER_SIZE);
    String str;
    try
    {
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            file += str;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        return "";
    }
```